# Unable to link pyarrow header files into a cpp pybind11 project with CMakeFiles.txt due to linkage error

Tags: c++, cmake, pyarrow, pybind11, apache-arrow

So after reading the [ https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/integration/extending.html  ](Apache Python Extending Documentation), Arrow CPP no longer includes PyArrow header files and those header files are included in the PyArrow. I am able to identify the locations of the pyarrow files which is at ${CONDA_PRFIX}/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/include.

In my CMakeFiles.txt, I added

```
set(PYARROW_INCLUDE_DIR "${Python_SITELIB}/pyarrow/include")
set(PYARROW_INCLUDE_LOCAL_DIR "<HARDCODED_PATH>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/include")
IF(EXISTS ${PYARROW_INCLUDE_DIR})
    message(STATUS "Found and using pyarrow include dir: ${PYARROW_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    include_directories(${PYARROW_INCLUDE_DIR})
ELSEIF(EXISTS ${PYARROW_INCLUDE_LOCAL_DIR})
    message(STATUS "Found and using local development pyarrow include dir: ${PYARROW_INCLUDE_LOCAL_DIR}")
    include_directories(${PYARROW_INCLUDE_LOCAL_DIR})
#    target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PYARROW_INCLUDE_LOCAL_DIR})
ELSE()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "pyarrow include dir not found")
ENDIF() 

...

pybind11_add_module(${PROJECT_NAME} pyluban_cpp_ext.cpp ${SRCS_CODE})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE pybind11::module Arrow::arrow_shared GTest::gtest_main ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PYARROW_INCLUDE_LOCAL_DIR})
```

The purpose of this is to enable custom casting between Python and C++ for PyArrow Tables:

```
#include <arrow/python/pyarrow.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
#include <arrow/table.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

namespace PYBIND11_NAMESPACE { namespace detail {
        template <> struct type_caster<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>> {
        public:
        PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>, _("pyarrow::Table"));

        bool load(handle src, bool) {
            PyObject *source = src.ptr();
            if (!arrow::py::is_table(source))
                return false;
            arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>> result = arrow::py::unwrap_table(source);
            if(!result.ok())
                return false;
            value = result.ValueOrDie();
            return true;
        }

        static handle cast(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> src, return_value_policy /* policy */, handle /* parent */) {
            return arrow::py::wrap_table(src);
        }
    };
}} // namespace PYBIND11_NAMESPACE::detail
```

I was able to build the pybind11 module with CMake

```bash
rm -rf build
cmake -S . -B build
cmake --build build -j 2
cmake --install build --prefix $CONDA_PREFIX
```

But when I tried importing the Python module, I had this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/project_name/build/pyluban_cpp_ext.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (__ZN5arrow2py10wrap_tableERKNSt3__110shared_ptrINS_5TableEEE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project_name/build/test_script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from project_name import RollingTableManager
ImportError: dlopen(/project_name/build/project_name.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (__ZN5arrow2py10wrap_tableERKNSt3__110shared_ptrINS_5TableEEE)
```

which is clear that I had linking issues for the header files in pyarrow. This is the results of `tree -L 2` at "<HARDCODED_PATH>/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/include":

```
.
└── arrow
    ├── acero
    ├── adapters
    ├── api.h
    ├── array
    ├── array.h
    ├── buffer.h
    ├── buffer_builder.h
    ├── builder.h
    ├── c
    ├── chunk_resolver.h
    ├── chunked_array.h
    ├── compare.h
    ├── compute
    ├── config.h
    ├── csv
    ├── dataset
    ├── datum.h
    ├── device.h
    ├── engine
    ├── extension
    ├── extension_type.h
    ├── filesystem
    ├── flight
    ├── io
    ├── ipc
    ├── json
    ├── memory_pool.h
    ├── memory_pool_test.h
    ├── pch.h
    ├── pretty_print.h
    ├── python
    ├── record_batch.h
    ├── result.h
    ├── scalar.h
    ├── sparse_tensor.h
    ├── status.h
    ├── stl.h
    ├── stl_allocator.h
    ├── stl_iterator.h
    ├── table.h
    ├── table_builder.h
    ├── tensor
    ├── tensor.h
    ├── testing
    ├── type.h
    ├── type_fwd.h
    ├── type_traits.h
    ├── util
    ├── vendored
    ├── visit_array_inline.h
    ├── visit_data_inline.h
    ├── visit_scalar_inline.h
    ├── visit_type_inline.h
    ├── visitor.h
    └── visitor_generate.h
```

Does anyone have any idea what did I do wrong in the CMakeFiles part?

I tried to link pyarrow header files into my C++ arrow pybind11 project for creating a python module. However I am unable to link up the header files successfully and I am asking for advices here on what went wrong.

Comment: It looks like you've added the pyarrow headers to your `include_directories`, but you have not added the pyarrow library to `target_link_libraries `. I'm not sure what value should be added on top of `Arrow::arrow_shared`. In the past I've used `arrow_python`

Comment: If this is a new project then I would recommend using the C data interface to transfer data between your extension and pyarrow.  I have an example of how to do this [here](https://github.com/westonpace/arrow-cdata-example). This way you won't have to link pyarrow at all (only arrow-cpp)

Comment: thanks @0x26res in the end, i had to use a arrow==9.0.0, sad that it is kind of unclear how to handle such scenario with arrow>=10.0.0

Comment: @Pace That is a good suggestion and I did spend some time investigating. Unfortunately, the C data interface only works for more simple data structure such as Array. When using ChunkArray/Table etc, it seems a bit too much effort. Thanks for the suggestion though.